# Error in pkg-config

Tags: opencv, debian, pi

I installed Debian OS on Rpi. While installing opencv, I create **"opencv.pc"** file in **"/home/pi/Opencv-2.4.3/release/lib"**. Then I entered following two commands:

1. sudo gedit /etc/bash.bashrc

Add the following two lines to the “bash.bashrc” file and save the file:
**PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/home/pi/Opencv-2.4.3/release/lib/pkgconfig
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH**

Then I got following errors after entered these commands:

1. chmod +x build_all.sh
2. /build_all.sh

What is the solution?

**errors are..**

```
Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv' found

Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv' found

contours.c:1:39: fatal error: opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
compiling convert_cascade.c
Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv' found..etc..
```

Answer (score 5):

To add the correct path to your bashrc you can do the following steps

1. *sudo find / -name "opencv.pc" -type f*
2. notice the directory output from 1. (without filename)
3. open /etc/bash.bashrc *sudo vi /etc/bash/bash.bashrc*
4. find and edit or add the following lines

   PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/your/path/from/#1

   export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
5. save your file *:wq*
6. logout and login again to active the changes

Comment: I got this issue, too, in a Debian with custom install of OpenCV 2.4.9.
> sudo find / -name "opencv.pc" -type f ***
/opt/OpenCV/OpenCV-2.4.9/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc ***
> echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH ***
/opt/OpenCV/OpenCV-2.4.9/lib/pkgconfig